# Need to position an element on an svg-background responsively

Tags: css, svg, background, css-position, responsive

I'm trying to create an container with a SVG as an Background. The Problem is if resize the viewport (responsive) my Elements dont be on the blue SVG ring because the position of the svg changes. The position of the SVG must be fixed and must not change depending on its size.

[Normal Viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nuNF.png)

[Smaller Viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPAOH.png)

Code:

```css
.service {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20rem 0 0 0;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.top {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 10rem 0 0;
}
.bot {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 1rem 0 0 10rem;
}
.circleu {
    height: 170rem;
    z-index: -1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 0 -10rem 0;
    background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Vt2.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: cover;
}

.infobox {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.box1 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 25rem;
    width: 20rem;
    border: solid 2px grey;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    margin: 5rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box1 img {
    height: 8rem;
    margin: -2rem 0 0 0;
}
.box1 h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.box1 p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 1rem 0 0 0;

}

.box2 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 25rem;
    width: 20rem;
    border: solid 2px grey;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    margin: 5rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box2 img {
    height: 8rem;
    margin: -2rem 0 0 0;
}
.box2 h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.box2 p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 1rem 0 0 0;

}

.box3 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 25rem;
    width: 20rem;
    border: solid 2px grey;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    margin: 5rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box3 img {
    height: 8rem;
    margin: -2rem 0 0 0;
}
.box3 h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.box3 p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 1rem 0 0 0;

}

.box4 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 25rem;
    width: 20rem;
    border: solid 2px grey;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    margin: 5rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box4 img {
    height: 8rem;
    margin: -2rem 0 0 0;
}
.box4 h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.box4 p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 1rem 0 0 0;

}
.info {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 2rem 0 0 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: #00B4FF;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.aboutus {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.about h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}
.about p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
}

.mini {
    width: 60rem;
    height: 30rem;
    margin: 15rem -5rem 0 0;
    background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/VrW.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 13rem 0rem;
}


.kontakt {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 8rem 0 0 0;
}
.title {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #8D8D8D;
  padding: 10px;
}
.form {
    margin: 0 150px 0 0;
}
.name {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
  width: 440px;
  height: 53px;
}
.email {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
  width: 440px;
  height: 53px;
}
.message {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
  width: 440px;
  height: 249px;
}
.input {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
}

.absenden {
  display: block;
  margin: 25px 0 0 0;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="circleu">
    <div class="service">
        <h2 class="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
        <h2 class="bot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="infobox">
            <div class="box1">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>-Lorem ipsum <br>
                    -Lorem ipsum <br>
                    -Lorem ipsum</p>
                <button class="info" onclick="thanks()">Erfahre mehr</button>
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>-Lorem ipsum <br>
                    -Lorem ipsum <br>
                    -Lorem ipsum </p>
                <button class="info" onclick="thanks()">Erfahre mehr</button>
            </div>
            <div class="box3">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>-Lorem ipsumt <br>
                    -Lorem ipsum  <br>
                    -Lorem ipsum </p>
                <button class="info" onclick="thanks()">Erfahre mehr</button>
            </div>
            <div class="box4">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>-Lorem ipsum <br>
                    -Lorem ipsum <br>
                    -Lorem ipsum </p>
                <button class="info" onclick="thanks()">Erfahre mehr</button>
            </div>
    </div>

  
    <div class="aboutus">
            <div class="about">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam <br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam <br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam<br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam <br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam <br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam  </p>
            </div>
            <div class="mini">
            </div>
    </div>

  
    <div class="kontakt">
        <form class="form">
        <div class="pageTitle title">Kontakt</div>
        <input type="text" class="name input" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="text" class="email input" placeholder="Email"/>
        <textarea class="message input" placeholder="Nachricht"></textarea>
        <button class="absenden" onclick="thanks()">Absenden</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

How can i avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
.circleu {
  background-position: 100% center;
}
```

Comment: no the behaviour is the same but thanks anyway